# Rooting Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I'm trying to root my Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9500 and I'm wondering that is there any way to root it without using PC and without losing any of my data. Currently I am running on Android 4.4.2 and have no custom ROM.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Towelroot](http://towelroot.com/) by geohot. He claims it roots all Android devices and versions within seconds ("should support all phones < jun 3 2014"). Didn't try it myself, no S4 available either, so I cannot tell for sure. No PC needed, just run the app. Don't forget to report back whether it worked :)

Comment: Izzy brother, I've tried that but what happens is that after I click make it rain, it automatically reboots which is OK but then when i check whether I have root access or not then it says that you don't have proper root access. Even the SuperSU says that super SU /superuser binary are not installed. What to do?

Comment: As I wrote, I've not tried that. You could check for instructions searching e.g. with Google for "towelroot". Or wait until someone else gives a proper answer. *Towelroot* itself includes neither a `su` binary (at least I couldn't find that inside the `.apk`) nor any *SuperUser*/*SuperSU* app, so that part might be normal. According to the instructions I've found, you need at least to manually install *the latest* *SuperSU* (by chainfire, released a few days ago).

Comment: Hey,by the way thanks brother, it was a nice effort but not working for me. I'm unlucky maybe. Thanks again

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to try the Kingroot app, will it? Here: http://www.kingroot.net

Answer (score 2):

Errr.. For this rooting problem, I have checked so many informations before. "Rooting" seems a little complicated and technical. However, it's really simple. The most important thing is to find a secure and easy tool for free rooting. Then, find a way to backup the file and data on Samsung Galaxy S4. Actually rooting won't cause data loss, but processes like unlocking bootloader will. So it's still important to backup the data before rooting.

Luckily, Samsung Galaxy S4 doesn't need to unlock bootloader like HTC or Nexus phones. You need focus on one thing: not bricking your device.

You can follow the steps on [how to root Samsung Galaxy S4](http://www.iroot.com/how-to-articles/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-s4.html) here. Ensure you have working ADB before continuing. Preferably, install Samsung Kies and the drivers that come with it, and some ADB/fastboot package or the Android SDK from Google.

1. Download iRoot on your Windows PC.
2. Connect your phone to your PC.
3. Detect the device and click on "Root Now".
4. Done!

Hope you have succeeded now.

Comment: Did you read the OP's question properly? It said "way to root it  **without** using PC". This isn't an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. What I want to put is that rooting with computer has the higher success rate than without computer. Also, the tool in this guide can root the Samsung Galaxy S4 without computer. Last, the backup issue is important in this thread. And I think it's more convenient  to do this on computer. Sorry again that you think my reply is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I rooted my SCH-i545 using [Towelroot](https://towelroot.com/) and it worked fine. Towelroot only works if the S4 is still on KitKat with the NC5 kernel (or earlier). If you're on a later kernel, [refer to this XDA tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-verizon/general/how-to-root-i545vrufnk1-4-4-2-12-1-2014-t2959613/post57189674#post57189674) to flash the compatible kernel.

Answer (score -1):

I've just rooted via following the instructions here http://www.android.gs/root-xxufnb8-android-4-4-2-official-rom-for-galaxy-s4-lte-i9505/

I'd strongly recommend that you search for and download Odin and Chainfire from the original sources and not via the links though as they look suspicious. Took about 10 mins in total. Good luck

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies.